# recursively adding an element to the end of a linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, data-structures, linked-list

I'm trying to add an element to the end of a linked list. I pass in the pointer as the first parameter(pass by value), but the head was originally set to null, I suppose that's the reason why my head never gets updated by the function. if this is the reason, could someone give me a hint as how to do this correctly?

```
Node* linkedList::addToEnd(Node* curr,int info)
  {
    Node* newInfo = new Node(info);
    if(curr==nullptr)
    {
      curr= newInfo;
      size++;
      return curr;
    }
    curr->next= addToEnd(curr->next, info);
    return curr;
  }
```

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

hello, this is me after solving the issue. I forgot that we could access private attributes in the functions. So simply add the following code will solve the issue(not updated head);

```
if(size==1)
head=curr;
```

Comment: `Node* curr;` you probably want to delete this line, it shadows the function parameter with the same name, also because its not initialized this is undefined behavior.

Comment: If head is null, your list is empty. So assign the new node to head. Draw pictures of this. It helps. Tail pointer is always worth having, even in a C-style linked list.

Comment: One problem I see from this implementation is that you're creating a bunch of Nodes from ```Node * newInfo= new Node(info);```. This is a memory leak since they never get deleted. Are you required to do this recursively? If not, it's significantly easier to do it iteratively.

Comment: You only want to call `Node* newInfo = new Node(info);` when `curr==nullptr`

Comment: hi, thank you for all the responses!!  i am required to do this recursively, and I'm sorry for the extra line of code, I didn't have it in original my program. I've fixed it by adding head=curr when size==1.

Comment: Here is a working example: https://onlinegdb.com/SJbGnT4k7u

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I think your demo retained the memory leak identified by Wes

Comment: @drescherjm Yes.  I did that on purpose.  You can see in the logging that it writes that it is allocating the same node over and over and never freeing anything.  The idea wasn't for me to fix his code but to help him understand why it was wrong.  I would have written it differently but then it would have been an answer.  Maybe I should write an answer but then I'm just stealing your comment for my own answer which seems unfair...  you should really write the answer.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I see now. Thanks for the explanation.